# How to autoload helpers under lib folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I called `sampleA` or `sampleB` in any action of controller

I will get `NoMethodError: undefined method`

How could I call the `sampleA or sampleB` in any controller ?

### application.rb

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib/)
```

### lib/custome_helper.rb

```
module CustomeHelper
  def sampleA

  end
  def sampleB

  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`include CustomeHelper` first in controller, then call `sampleA` or `sampleB`

Comment: Please add an explaination why you think that this solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have added `lib` to `config.autoload_paths` which means that you don't have to manually require the file path. However, you still need to include the module in your controller in order to use `sampleA` and `sampleB`. For example:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  include CustomeHelper

  def index
    sampleA
  end
end
```

Using `include CustomeHelper` mixes CustomeHelper's methods into the UsersController.